# Ajax helper tags documentation in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is there is any link for Ajax helper tags documentation in Asp.net Core. I am trying to learn ajax with asp.net core but i found no documentation for it. 
In asp.net mvc we use @Ajax.Form and then uses AjaxOptions method for work on ajax. After many hours search i found this link. 
https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/
In this link there is a way work with ajax in asp.net core.
I implement it in my project and successful. 
Then i search for its documentation but i found nothing.
I want its documentation link.Please anybody help for its documentation

Comment: If you want to lean ajax, the use`jQuery.ajax()`, not the obsolete `Ajax` methods

Comment: Are Ajax tag helper obsolete ????
This is an easy method in asp.net core for working with ajax. as i mention above a link

Comment: I think the general direction you should head is to write JavaScript to write JavaScript. So no, there are no server-side helpers in ASP.NET Core by default. `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` is a JavaScript package that adds client side behavior to look for various attributes to add functionality on top of your standard form. There does not seem to be documentation about it though, so you would have to look at its source for more information: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

Comment: The `Ajax.BeginForm()` and `Ajax.ActionLink()` helpers have not been included in mvc-core. MS don't recommend it.  Its not being updated anymore. It was always just a wrapper around the `$.ajax()` methods anyway, and the `$.ajax()` methods give you far more flexibility

Comment: Thanks @poke 
Now i understand whats going on in the background.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke 
It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are no server-side helpers, like `@Ajax.Form`, in ASP.NET Core. You could probably write your own tag helpers for similar features but I haven’t seen anyone do this. The general idea is to write actual JavaScript when you want to have client-side behavior. Hiding these things behind server-side magic is usually not the best idea.

[`jquery-ajax-unobtrusive`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) is a JavaScript package that adds client-side behavior to look for various attributes in the final rendered page to add functionality on top of your standard forms. So this would be a fully JavaScript-based solution.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be documentation about it. You can take a look at [its source code](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) to figure out what may or may not be possible.

---

#### `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` documentation

From taking a quick look at the source (disclaimer: without testing the functionality myself), this seems to be the supported data attributes and available functionality of the package:

- `data-ajax="true"` – To enable the functionality for a form.
- `data-ajax-update` – Selector for the elements that are updated with the AJAX result, using the mode.
- `data-ajax-mode`

  - `data-ajax-mode="before"` – [Prepends](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the data to the element.
  - `data-ajax-mode="after"` – [Appends](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the data to the element.
  - `data-ajax-mode="replace-with"` – [Replaces](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) the element with the data.
  - Otherwise [sets the HTML content](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) of the element to the data.
- `data-ajax-confirm` – Message that is displayed to the user to [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) the form submission.
- `data-ajax-loading` – Selector of element that is shown while loading.
- `data-ajax-loading-duration` (default: 0) – Animation duration for [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) of the loading element.
- `data-ajax-method` – Allows overwriting the HTTP method for the AJAX request.
- `data-ajax-url` – Allows overwriting the URL for the AJAX request.
- `data-ajax-cache` – Set to other value than `"true"` to disable the [jQuery AJAX `cache` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- `data-ajax-begin` – Callback function before the request starts (arguments: `xhr`)
- `data-ajax-complete` – Callback function when the request is completed (arguments: `xhr`, `status`)
- `data-ajax-success` – Callback function when the request was successful (arguments: `data`, `status`, `xhr`)
- `data-ajax-failure` – Callback function when the request failed (arguments: `xhr`, `status`, `error`)

The callback functions are the equivalent of jQuery’s `beforeSend`, `complete`, `success`, and `failure`. From how it looks, you can specify the callbacks using a JavaScript object path to the function.

For example `data-ajax-success="foo.bar.onSuccess"` will call the function `foo.bar.onSuccess()`, i.e. it will look for an object `foo` in the `window`, get its `bar` member, and call `onSuccess` on that.

Comment: … and suddenly there was documentation for the package xD

Comment: Is there any method for **abort()** ing the request?

Comment: @Vikrant Returning `false` from the `data-ajax-begin` method seems to work. Though you've probably found that by now...

Comment: Yes @Auspex, I did but thanks a lot for correct input. ;)

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Behrouz-Goudarzi/AjaxTagHelper

AjaxTagHelper

A simple solution to using links and ajax forms using Tag Helper in aspnet core

First, copy the AjaxTagHelper class from the Extensions folder to your project.

Second, copy the AjaxTagHelper.js file from js folder in wwwroot and add it to your project.

Then do the following: Open the viewImports file and add the following code

```
@using AjaxTagHelper.Extensions
@using AjaxTagHelper
@using AjaxTagHelper.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AjaxTagHelper
```

To use Action Ajax, add the following code instead of the tag.

```
  <ajax-action ajax-action="Delete" ajax-controller="Home" ajax-data-id="@Model.Id"
                 class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ajax-success-func="SuccessDelete">
        Delete
    </ajax-action>
```

Use the following code to use AJAX to send the form to server.

```
<div class="row">
    <form id="frmCreate" class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-control">
                <input placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" class="input-group" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-control">
                <input placeholder="Enter Family" name="Family" class="input-group" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-control">
                <input placeholder="Enter Email@site.com " name="Email" class="input-group" type="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ajax-button ajax-controller="Home" ajax-action="Create" ajax-form-id="frmCreate" ajax-success-func="SuccessCreate"
                     class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Create
        </ajax-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, add the scripts you need to view it, check the code below

```
<script>
    function SuccessCreate(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#tbodyPerson").append(data);


    }
    function SuccessDelete(data) {
        $("#tr" + data.id).fadeOut();
    }
</script>
<script src="~/js/AjaxHelper.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the old style Ajax helpers in Core, this Nuget package might help -

> AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax

You can install it using -

```
PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

This will enable you to use helpers like

```
@Html.AjaxActionLink()
@Html.AjaxBeginForm()
@Html.AjaxRouteLink()
```

Here's the github details. You can find more documentation in there.

[Github Url to the project](https://github.com/mjebrahimi/AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax)