# How to create AJAX Form in Asp.Net Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

```
<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#results" asp-action="CreateCarClient" asp-controller="Account" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This form doesn't work.

Comment: There are lots of examples available in the internet. Try one of them and if you have a concrete problem, post it. Please describe what you expect your code to do, what it does and where you have a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You are using [jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148418/ajax-helper-tags-documentation-in-asp-net-core) in ASP.NET Core.You need to install the  jquery.unobtrusive-ajax package into your project using `npm install jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` and add references to it in your view.

See tutorials of razor pages [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax).

[This link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2148353.aspx) displays my example of how to use the code step by step.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution of `Ajax.BeginForm` as everything is available in this package

Only thing change is `Html.AjaxBeginForm`

```
PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

[Reference is here](https://github.com/mjebrahimi/AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax)

Answer (score 2):

If you attempting to do this in .NET 5 then add the JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax libraries to your project as you normally would, then write your own little tag helper!

This one is VERY basic but you can expand on it as you wish.

```
namespace MyProject.Helpers.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("form", Attributes ="ajax")]
    public class AjaxForm : TagHelper
    {
        public string replaceId { get; set; }
        public string onAjaxBegin { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-ajax", "true");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-ajax-method", "POST");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-ajax-mode", "replace");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("method", "post");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", id);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(onAjaxBegin))
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-ajax-begin", onAjaxBegin);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replaceId))
                throw new Exception("ReplaceId is required!");

            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-ajax-update", $"#{replaceId.TrimStart('#')}");
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to register this tag helper in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`

```
@addTagHelper  MyProject.Helpers.TagHelpers.*, MyProject
```

Usage Example:

```
<form id="GandalfForm" ajax replace-id="partialViewWrapper" on-ajax-begin="OnBeginDoSomethingInJavascript" asp-controller="SomeController" asp-action="SomeMethod">
    <div id="partialViewWrapper">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/SampleContent.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
```

Note that the "ReplaceId" DOM element must start with a `#` in order for the unobtrusive ajax library to work correctly.