# Cannot get AJAX/jquery-unobtrusive to work in Asp.Net Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core app (.NET Core 2.1).  It was created in Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4.

Every attempt I've made to get AJAX seem to fail and jquery unobstrusive validation stuff isn't working either.  In the _Layout.cshtml file below there is a link in the navbar `<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DoSomething" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">Do Something</a>` that I've been trying to get working.  The method is being completely ignored, this is always being sent as a GET and it does a full postback and navigates to Home/DoSomething which I don't think it should do.  The controller method just returns `Json(true)` currently.  I'm not seeing any javascript errors either.  Anyone got any idea what I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.metro.mobile.min.css" />

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-rZfj/ogBloos6wzLGpPkkOr/gpkBNLZ6b6yLy4o+ok+t/SAKlL5mvXLr0OXNi1Hp">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.9/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-ifv0TYDWxBHzvAk2Z0n8R434FL1Rlv/Av18DXE43N/1rvHyOG4izKst0f2iSLdds">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">@ViewData["Title"]</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-app-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DoSomething" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">Do Something</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2019 - Me</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148418/ajax-helper-tags-documentation-in-asp-net-core and this is also helpful https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot call the post request to DoSomething method when you click the link ?Do you use the browser's developer tool F12 to check if there is the error ?

Comment: @XueliChen No errors in the dev tool console.  The issue is it's always doing a postback when I don't think it should for an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js you quoted does not work. I made the test demo , and it worked well.
The jquery.unobtrusive-ajax scripts I used in _layout.cshtml

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
</environment>
```

You could downloadjquery.validate.unobtrusive.js from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) and add it to your wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive

Comment: So basically what Visual Studio scaffolds out when you create new project is broken?