# Return JSON with ajax is giving me blank page with return parameters

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I started learning AJAX like this week and I was trying to make a simple voting thingy on page in asp mvc - when you click one button you get message like a popup (in browser) and count increments, when you click second, you get another count decrements, you get the idea.
I wanted to test it's possible to do like voting system (upvotes/downvotes) that will update itself's oount on click without needing to refresh the page.
However, when I click on this buttons, it gets me blank page with the things that return json contains. (picture included at the very bottom of post).
I am most likely missing something obvious, so please bear with me and if you could navigate me where am I wrong, please do.

My Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            Vote vote = new Vote();
            vote.Votes = 0;
            return View(vote);
        }

        


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VoteUp(string plus, string minus)
        {
            Vote vote = new Vote();

            if (plus == null)
            {
               
                vote.Votes = vote.Votes -1;
                var message = "You voted down";
                return Json(new { success = true, message = message }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
            }
            else if ((minus == null))
            {
                
                vote.Votes = vote.Votes +1 ;
                var messagez = "You voted up";
                return Json(new { success = true, message = messagez }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
            }
            else { }
            var messagebad = "STH WENT WRONG";
            return Json(new { success = true, message = messagebad }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
        }
```

My View:

```
@model JSON_RETURN.Models.Vote
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "sssss";
}




<form  asp-action="VoteUp" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" data-ajax="true">


    <div class="form-group"> </div>



    <div class="input-group-button">
        <button name="plus" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="" value="1" >+</button>
        @Model.Votes

        <button name="minus" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="" value="-1" >-</button>

    </div>

</form>


    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/lib/ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

                function SubmitForm(form) {
                    form.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "HomeController/VoteUp",  //form.action,
                    data: ('#form'),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            alert(data.message);
                        } else {

                        }
                    },

                });
                
               
              

            };


        </script>
    }
```

My Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace JSON_RETURN.Models
{
    public class Vote
    {
        public int Votes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And there's the blank page I'm getting every click (message varies ofc):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hdZx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is just a form submit instead of using ajax. Why it return json string that is because you return json string in your backend code(`return Json(new { success = true, message = messagebad }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());`).

I saw you use `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your code, also you create a js function with ajax. Actually, you just need to choose one of the two ways to achieve your requrement.

Here is the correct way of using `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` :

**Note:**

1.If you use asp.net core, it contains `jquery.js` in _Layout.cshtml by default. So when you use `@section Scripts{}`, no need add the `jquery.js` again. If your _Layout.cshtml **does not contain** `jquery.js`, you need add this js file before `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`:

> ```
> <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="~/lib/ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
> ```

2.You need specific `data-ajax-update` to tell the elements where need to be updated with the AJAX result.

More supported data attributes for `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148838/11398810).

View:

```
@model Vote
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "sssss";
}
<div id="result"> //add this div...
                                                                 //add this...
    <form asp-action="VoteUp" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" data-ajax-update="#result" data-ajax="true">
        <div class="form-group"> </div>
        <div class="input-group-button">
            <button name="plus" class="btn btn-dark" value="1">+</button>
            @Model.Votes
            <input hidden asp-for="Votes" />         //add this....
            <button name="minus" class="btn btn-dark" value="-1">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha256-v2nySZafnswY87um3ymbg7p9f766IQspC5oqaqZVX2c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

}
```

Controller:

**Note:**  You can see that I add a hidden input for `Votes` in form, that is because only input or select type of element can be post to backend. The reason for why I want to get `Votes` value is because your code always create a new instance for Vote, the value will always plus start with `0`.

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    Vote vote = new Vote();
    vote.Votes = 0;
    return View(vote);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VoteUp(string plus, string minus)
{
    Vote vote = new Vote();
    vote.Votes = int.Parse(Request.Form["Votes"]); 
    if (plus == null)
    {

        vote.Votes = vote.Votes - 1;
    }
    else if ((minus == null))
    {

        vote.Votes = vote.Votes + 1;
    }
    else { }
    return PartialView("Privacy", vote);
}
```

Result:

[image]