# How to replace Ajax.BeginForm helper in .Net Core 6.0 application since Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax is deprecated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

In previous ASP.NET MVC projects, I've made much use of the `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper in Razor pages to create forms that update content within a page and update only a portion of the page. Now I am creating a project in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and I don't know how Microsoft would like me to achieve the same thing.

All my google searches so far turn up posts that are a few years old and point me to the nuget package `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`, but that hasn't been updated since 2018 and is currently marked as deprecated. I'm not finding any tag helpers that allow partial updating of a page after a form post. I'm not opposed to adding custom jQuery if that's the only remaining route, but I'm not finding good examples of that yet, either.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-practical-es6-guide-on-how-to-perform-http-requests-using-the-fetch-api-594c3d91a547/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ASP.NET 6, it is **common use** `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and define the form somthing like below:

```
<div id="result">
<form asp-action="ActionName" asp-controller="ControllerName" method="POST" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="result">
    <!-- form content-->
</form>
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha256-v2nySZafnswY87um3ymbg7p9f766IQspC5oqaqZVX2c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
}
```

More supported `data-*` attributes for `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148838/11398810).

| Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- |
| data-ajax | Must be set to `true` to activate unobtrusive Ajax on the target element. |
| data-ajax-confirm | Gets or sets the message to display in a confirmation window before a request is submitted. |
| data-ajax-method | Gets or sets the HTTP request method ("Get" or "Post"). |
| data-ajax-mode | Gets or sets the mode that specifies how to insert the response into the target DOM element. Valid values are `before`, `after` and `replace`. Default is `replace` |
| data-ajax-loading-duration | Gets or sets a value, in milliseconds, that controls the duration of the animation when showing or hiding the loading element. |
| data-ajax-loading | Gets or sets the id attribute of an HTML element that is displayed while the Ajax function is loading. |
| data-ajax-begin | Gets or sets the name of the JavaScript function to call immediately before the page is updated. |
| data-ajax-complete | Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call when response |
| data-ajax-failure | Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call if the page update fails. |
| data-ajax-success | Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call after the page is successfully updated. |
| data-ajax-update | Gets or sets the ID of the DOM element to update by using the response from the server. |
| data-ajax-url | Gets or sets the URL to make the request to |

A simple demo you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70060460/11398810).

Another way which is similiar to `Ajax.BeginForm()` is using the package `AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax`, you can check the github repo here:https://github.com/mjebrahimi/AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax